# Trouble creating the quickstart application

Tags: daml

I am working through the [Digital Asset quickstart guide](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html) and I am unable to run:

```
da new quickstart-java quickstart
```

I get the following output:

```
getting-started Built-in template for version: 0.10.9-SDK
example-bond-trading Built-in template for version: 0.0.7
example-collateral Built-in template for version: 1.0.6
example-ping-pong-grpc-java Built-in template for version: 2.2.0
example-ping-pong-reactive-components-java Built-in template for version: 2.2.0
example-ping-pong-reactive-java Built-in template for version: 2.2.0
example-repo-market Built-in template for version: 0.0.5
example-upgrade Built-in template for version: 0.0.6
```

It seems "quickstart-java" is not an available template. Is there a way for me to install it?

I tried running it with 'getting-started' instead of 'quickstart-java' but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm which version of the SDK you have? Do `da list` at a terminal prompt and look for the active and default version. From the output, it looks like you have version 0.10.9. You'll need to upgrade to 0.11.X - latest is 0.11.3

Here's the output on my terminal:

```
paul:da (master)$ da list
Installed SDK releases:
  0.10.0 
  0.10.2 
  0.10.3 
  0.10.6 
  0.10.8 
  0.10.9 
  0.10.12 
  0.10.13 
  0.11.0 
  0.11.1 
  0.11.2 
  0.11.3 (active, default)
paul:da (master)$
```

You can use the command `da use 0.11.3` once you have upgraded to set the default SDK version for new projects.